# Vertx Web Client throwing HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type for Multipart/form-data

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vert.x-webclient

This service receives the multipart request from mobile client and passes on the request to downstream service for uploading the image. I am seeing 415 Unsupported Media Type in my downstream service

```
 private void makeRequest(HttpRequest<Buffer> httpRequest,
                             Promise<Object> future,
                             RequestContext requestContext,
                             RoutingContext routingContext,
                             Entry entry) {
        MultipartForm multipartForm = MultipartForm.create();
        MultiMap attributes = routingContext.request()
                .formAttributes();
        attributes.forEach(attribute -> {
            multipartForm.attribute(attribute.getKey(), attribute.getValue());
        });
        routingContext.fileUploads()
                .forEach(fileUpload -> {
                    multipartForm.binaryFileUpload(fileUpload.name(), fileUpload.fileName(),
                            fileUpload.uploadedFileName(), fileUpload.contentType());
                });

        httpRequest.sendMultipartForm(multipartForm, response -> {
            handleResponse(routingContext, future, response, requestContext, entry);
        });
    }
```

Getting the below exception

```
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.getMethodRouter(MethodSelectingRouter.java:478)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.access$000(MethodSelectingRouter.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter$4.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:779)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.MethodSelectingRouter.apply(MethodSelectingRouter.java:371)
```

API signature of my downstream service

```
@POST
    @Timed
    @Path("{userId}/{scope}/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation("Multipart upload of an image")
```

Can someone please guide what is wrong in my code snippet or is there any setting which needs to be enabled in vertx server or vertx web client?

Thanks,
Nitish Goyal

Comment: Seems you don't set the correct header on your request. Use `.putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")`
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_writing_request_bodies

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did help. I was under the impression that sendMultipartForm is setting content type header inside the implementation. Post adding this header, I am getting now ```Caused by: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Reached EOF, but there is no closing MIME boundary```

Comment: @AlexeySoshin : I have made the changes you suggested, but post that after trying different size images, I am always getting ```Caused by: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Reached EOF, but there is no closing MIME boundary```. I try the same request on our previous api-gateway, it works fine. So, the end boundary is coming for sure from the client. Any insights here would be helpful

Comment: This is a different question, but I would suggest to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536054/how-can-i-fix-org-jvnet-mimepull-mimeparsingexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by explicitly setting the header
`.putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")`